# Add look up field in lightning-record-form with on lightning web component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

I want to know if there is a way to add look up field in lightning-record-form with on  lightning web component. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, lightning-record-for supports lookups. Are you facing any issue?

Comment: yes I look for an issue. thanks @TusharSharma ind advance.

Comment: If this answers your question then you can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, lightning-record-form supports lookups.

Here is the basic syntax for you.

```
<lightning-record-form
        record-id={recordId}
        object-api-name={objectApiName}
        layout-type="Full"
        fields={fields}
        columns="2"
        mode="edit">
</lightning-record-form>
```